# If $f_n\to f$ uniformly on each ball, does it follow that $\left|\frac{f_n(tx)}{f_n(sx)}-\frac{f(tx)}{f(sx)}\right|\to0$ for all $s,t\in[0,1]$?

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $f_n,f:E\to\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ be uniformly continuous with $$\min\left(\inf_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}|f_n(x)|,\inf_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}|f(x)|\right)>0\;\;\;\text{for all }r>0\tag1$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $$\sup_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}|(f_n-f)(x)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{for all }r>0.\tag2$$

> Given $s,t\in[0,1]$, are we able to show $$\sup_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}\left|\frac{f_n(tx)}{f_n(sx)}-\frac{f(tx)}{f(sx)}\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag3$$ for all $r>0$?

Intuitively, $(3)$ should be true and actually I think that $(1)$ is not important for that. But how can we prove it rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that (2) is enough, together with the fact that $f_n(x), f(x)\neq 0$ for every $x$.
Specifically, let us fix $r>0$. By (2), the sequence is uniformly bounded on $\overline{B}_r$, hence there exists $M_r > 0$ such that
$$
|f(x)|, |f_n(x)| \leq M_r
\qquad \forall x\in \overline{B}_r,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Moreover, since $|f(x)|\neq 0$ for every $x$, again by (2) there exists $m_r > 0$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
m_r \leq |f(x)|, |f_n(x)|
\qquad\forall x\in \overline{B}_r, \ \forall n\geq N.
$$
Hence, for $n\geq N$, $t,s\in [0,1]$, $x\in \overline{B}_r$,
$$
\begin{split}
\left|\frac{f_n(tx)}{f_n(sx)} - \frac{f(tx)}{f(sx)}\right| 
 &\leq
\frac{1}{m_r^2} \left|f_n(tx) f(sx) - f(tx) f(sx) + f(tx) f(sx) - f_n(sx) f(tx)\right|
\\ & \leq
\frac{M_r}{m_r^2} \left( |f_n(tx) - f(tx)| + |f_n(sx) - f(sx)| \right)\,,
\end{split}
$$
and the claim follows again from (2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two remarks: (a) Note that you didn't use $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}|f_n(x)|\le M_r$; you've only used $\sup_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}|f(x)|\le M_r$. (b) Iin order to obtain the existence of $m_r$, I think you need that $c:=\frac12\inf_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}|f(x)|>0$, since then $(2)$ implies that there is a $n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $$2c-|f_n(x)|\le|f(x)|-|f_n(x)|\le|(f_n-f)(x)|<c$$ and hence $|f_n(x)|>c$ for all $x\in\overline B_r(0)$ and $n\ge n_0$. Now you can choose $m_r:=c$.